# Magento indexing blank page, status pending

Tags: magento, ssh

My indexing page keeps blank on the most recent version of Magento. I can't seem to find out why!

**What I've tried:**

Using SSH:

```
php -f indexer.php reindex all
```

I got a response that indexing will begin. So I **don't** receive this message:

```
Index process is working now. Please try run this process later
```

But each time I try to check the status, all I get is:

```
Product Attributes:            Pending
Product Prices:                Pending
Catalog URL Rewrites:          Pending
Product Flat Data:             Pending
Category Flat Data:            Pending
Category Products:             Pending
Catalog Search Index:          Pending
Stock Status:                  Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:          Pending
```

I also tried to set the indexing to "manual update" using SSH. This didn't fix the issue and I still got a blank page :(

How can I fix my blank indexing page?

**Edit:**
Problem was caused by a corrupt extension

Comment: Please check apache error log and magento log for any errors.

Comment: @Muk the Magento error log doesn't really contain any errors that are linked to this issue. Apache error log either :(

Comment: Delete all file from var/cache/ folder and var/session/ folder and then check...

Comment: @VishalSharma I tried that already, dind't fix the issue.

Comment: @Fidelity - Rather than edit the question you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a corrupt (partially uploaded) extension.